# How to add CSS styling from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

Quick disclaimer - I'm new to coding and JavaScript, and this is my first post so please go easy on me.

I have an array of Hex codes for colors and I want to use JQuery to style some empty div's in the HTML with the colors. The div's have a class of "square" and sit inside a main tag and have been given a height and width in CSS so I know they are there. I want to attach the array in order so the div's are colored in order.

This is my HTML:

```
<main>
  <div class="Sample">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

and this is the array:

```
let colors = ['#7e6493', '#895782', '#944a71', '#9f3c60', '#aa2f4f']
let $gameSquares = $('.square');
```

So ideally what I wanted was a function which changed the background colour of the div's one by one with the Hex colors from the array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "change the background colour of the div's one by one with the Hex colors from the array", do you mean all squares will start on the first colour and then all squares will move to the next colour in the array? OR: it will rotate colours differently for each square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
let colors = ['#7e6493', '#895782', '#944a71', '#9f3c60', '#aa2f4f']

$('.square').each(function(index, element){
    $(element).css("background-color", colors[index]);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Please clarify your question, if you only want to give this `background-color` property for `square` class you can use this pure CSS solution with pseudoclass `:nth-child(an+b)`:

```
square:nth-child(1){ #7e6493 };
square:nth-child(2){ #895782 };
square:nth-child(3){ #944a71 };
square:nth-child(4){ #9f3c60 };
square:nth-child(5){ #aa2f4f };
```

[more about nth-child from MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let colors = ['#7e6493', '#895782', '#944a71', '#9f3c60', '#aa2f4f']
let $gameSquares = $('.square');

$gameSquares.each(function(idx, el) {
  $(el).css('backgroundColor', colors[idx]);
});
```

```css
.square
{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   float: left;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div class="Sample">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: This should apply the colors sequentially through your divs. If you would like different functionality, please clarify your original question.

Answer (score 1):

```
colors = ['#7e6493', '#895782', '#944a71', '#9f3c60', '#aa2f4f'];
i = 0;
totalColors = colors.length;
$('.square').each( function(){
   $(this).css('backgroundColor', colors[i]);
   if (i >= totalColors){
      i = 0;
   } else {
      i++;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var colorSquares = function( $squares, colors ) {
    $squares.each( function( i ) {
        if ( colors[ i ] ) {
            $( this ).css( 'background-color', colors[ i ] );
        }
    } );
}

colorBoxes( $gameSquares, colors );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to deal with [children() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_children.asp) and [first() child method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_first.asp) then use it together like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colors = ['#7e6493', '#895782', '#944a71', '#9f3c60', '#aa2f4f']
  var i = 0;
  // Getting first square
  var $tempSquare = $('.sample').children().first();
  // console.log($tempSquare);

  while ($tempSquare.length && colors[i]) {
    // Changing current square background color
    $tempSquare.css("background-color", colors[i]);
    // Move to next sibling
    $tempSquare = $tempSquare.next();
    // console.log($tempSquare);
    // Increment index
    i++;
  }
});
```